# PuTTY: "Server's host key not cached" - but the fingerprint is wrong

Tags: ssh, server, key, putty, host

When trying to connect via PuTTY with SSH, I get the following warning:

> The server's host key is not cached in the registry. You have no
>   guarantee that the server is the computer you think it is. The
>   server's rsa2 key fingerprint is: ssh-rsa 1024
>   cc:2v:25:73:c8:a6:59:7e:b8:23:2d:13:3e:66:9b:b9 If you trust this
>   host, enter "y" to add the key to PuTTY's cache and carry on
>   connecting. If you want to carry on connecting just once, without
>   adding the key to the cache, enter "n". If you do not trust this host,
>   press Return to abandon the connection. Store key in cache? (y/n)
>   Connection abandoned.

The issue is, the fingerprint shown in the warning message is not the fingerprint to the key that I want to use. How do I change it?

Answer (score 0):

> The issue is, the fingerprint shown in the warning message is not the fingerprint to the key that I want to use. How do I change it?

That should not be. That is fingerprint of the key that belongs to the server you are connecting to.